# How to disable CURRENT DATE and PREVIOUS DATE'S for WeekDatePicker

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-calendar

Anyone knows how to disable `CURRENT DATE` and `PREVIOUS DATE'S` for `WeekDatePicker` in Android?

In normal DatePicker we can use this,

```
calendarView.newState().setMinimumDate(calendar.getTime()).commit();
calendarView.setLimits();

calendarView.addDecorator(new DayViewDecorator() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay calendarDay)

    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.setDaysDisabled(true);
    }
});
```

But how to disable `CURRENT DATE` and `PREVIOUS DATE'S` in `"WeekDatePicker"`?

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK named `WeekDatePicker`, `DayViewFacade`, `DayViewDecorator`, or `CalendarDay`. If these are coming from some library, please identify the library and consider using whatever support options are offered by the library's authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using [WeekDatePicker](https://github.com/blazsolar/WeekDatePicker/)

According to the documentation, `calendarView.setLimits()` has a `From` and `To` as arguments, so you could maybe try nulling the to and setting the from to the current date:

```
datePicker.setLimits(LocalDate.now(), null);
```

However, running this it seemed to leave the current day as selected, and when I added a day to this, it would then have the current date indicator as the day before. I've fixed this with the following code, which seems a bit hacky but seems to also work:

```
datePicker.setDateIndicator(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), true);
datePicker.setLimits(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1), null);
datePicker.selectDay(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1));
```

testing this it looks like it has the desired effect:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and ping you back.

Comment: @SathishKumar It looks like I got that back to front. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Super... Working Perfectly...   Thank you so much.